# Why error shows when use Math.pow

Tags: javascript, math

I've tried to get 2^64 in **Google Console**.

I got this below:

> Math.pow(2,64) = 18446744073709552000 (18,446,744,073,709,552,000)

And I tried another way:

```js
var x = 1;
for(var i=1;i<=64;i++){x*=2}
console.log(x);
```

Both two returned the same result.

I felt it's strange that it ends with zero, so I calculated by Windows calculator and then I got the result below:

> (((((2^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2 = 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.

Why the two results have such error?

I've tried to **Google** but I have no idea what keywords should I use.

Anything is appreciated and if this is duplicate please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint

Comment: God! thanks a lot! I've got this question asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin
Could anyone help me mark this question as duplicate?